# Confusion with React and handling of number inputs with decimal points

Tags: reactjs

I just started using react and noticed something that was bugging me. Can someone explain to me why the following behavior occurs when dealing with a controlled number input:

I have one input of type "number" with value set to `state.foo`. It's a controlled input element with an onChange event handler that basically stores the typed value into `state.foo`. With that in place, why does typing something like "1.." not clear out the input element, despite `state.foo` becoming empty (because "1.." isn't a number)? If I hit backspace to remove 1 dot ("1."), then retype the deleted dot ("1.."), all without losing focus on the input, the same behavior above persist. If I hit backspace though then click out of the input, "1." suddenly becomes "1". If I type in 1 leading dot ("1.") then click out of the input, the single dot stays this time. If I then type in another leading dot ("1..") then click out, the number element blanks out. Why the inconsistency?

Hopefully my explanation why clear enough. Below is a quick example to test this out. I only tried this on Chrome by the way

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GOXvmX

Comment: I can't repro the 1. to 1 - Even if you type 1.. (invalid input value), the input won't clear out the invalid input until you blur the input.

Comment: Weird. "1." immediately becomes "1" for me the first time the blur event is triggered. Once that happens, "1.." would then get cleared out just as you described. But if I immediately type "1.." in the beginning, then the input does not get cleared out. I wonder if it's a Chrome thing. Just tested with Firefox and the behavior there is slightly different (and more easier to understand)

Comment: It doesn't clear 1.. on first blur, weird. May be a browser quirk.